# Jekyll for GitHub Pages can't find rouge on Windows

Tags: windows, jekyll, rouge

I just installed Jekyll on Windows and I'm trying to make the syntax highlight work with rouge.

I have set `highlighter: rouge` on _config.yml.

In the file _posts\2015-08-13-my-first-post.md I got:

```
{% highlight javascript linenos %}
var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
alert(s);
{% endhighlight %}
```

When I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` it outputs:

```
C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Projects\GithubPage>bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: C:/Users/Fred/Documents/Projects/GithubPage/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Fred/Documents/Projects/GithubPage
       Destination: C:/Users/Fred/Documents/Projects/GithubPage/_site
      Generating...
  Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- rouge in _posts/2015-08-13-my-first-post.md
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:103:in `require': cannot load such file -- rouge (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:103:in `render_rouge'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:54:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:109:in `block in render_all'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `render_all'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:128:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:138:in `render!'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:106:in `render_liquid'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:233:in `do_layout'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/post.rb:261:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:298:in `block in render'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:297:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:297:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:51:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:56:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

The gems that I have installed are:

```
C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Projects\GithubPage>gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
bundler (1.10.6)
celluloid (0.16.1)
classifier-reborn (2.0.3)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
colorator (0.1)
execjs (2.5.2)
fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
ffi (1.9.10 x64-mingw32)
hitimes (1.2.2)
io-console (0.4.3)
jekyll (2.5.3)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-gist (1.3.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.3.0)
jekyll-watch (1.2.1)
json (1.8.1)
kramdown (1.8.0)
liquid (2.6.3)
listen (2.10.1)
mercenary (0.3.5)
minitest (4.7.5)
parslet (1.5.0)
posix-spawn (0.3.11)
psych (2.0.5)
pygments.rb (0.6.3)
rake (10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.1.0)
redcarpet (3.3.2)
rouge (1.9.1)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sass (3.4.16)
test-unit (2.1.6.0)
timers (4.0.1)
toml (0.1.2)
yajl-ruby (1.2.1)
```

Comment: I just received an automatic e-mail from GitHub saying that rouge is not supported in GitHub Pages. It seems that this could be the problem and I have no alternative other than installing Python and pygments.

Anyways, can anyone tell me if this is the reason of rouge not working on my development machine? Maybe because I'm using GitHub bundle. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: For future readers: See [this issue](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/pull/79).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I added the line

```
gem 'rouge'
```

to my Gemfile, then ran

```
bundle install
```

Then I could run

```
bundle exec jekyll build
```

without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages work only with [these](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/) plugins for security reasons.

Have you installed rouge in your Jekyll directory?

[Here](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/3-syntax-highlighting/) is a guide for syntax highlighting in Jekyll and installing Jekyll on a Windows machine that might help you.