# bundle exec jekyll serve > Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-commonmark-ghpages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to run `bundle exec jekyll build` but I get the below output.

```
Configuration file: /path/_config.yml
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-commonmark-ghpages or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- rouge' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  jekyll-commonmark-ghpages
```

I'm editing my site which is hosted on on GitHub pages. This process with jekyll has worked before but I haven't touched it for a long time.

I've tried to delete the Gemfile.lock and bundle install, I still get the same error though. I'm running Kubuntu 19.04, ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux-gnu].

My bundle show output:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * activesupport (4.2.11.1)
  * addressable (2.6.0)
  * bundler (2.0.2)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.11.1)
  * colorator (1.1.0)
  * commonmarker (0.17.13)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
  * dnsruby (1.61.2)
  * em-websocket (0.5.1)
  * ethon (0.12.0)
  * eventmachine (1.2.7)
  * execjs (2.7.0)
  * faraday (0.15.4)
  * ffi (1.11.1)
  * forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
  * gemoji (3.0.1)
  * github-pages (198)
  * github-pages-health-check (1.16.1)
  * html-pipeline (2.11.1)
  * http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
  * i18n (0.9.5)
  * jekyll (3.8.5)
  * jekyll-avatar (0.6.0)
  * jekyll-coffeescript (1.1.1)
  * jekyll-commonmark (1.3.1)
  * jekyll-commonmark-ghpages (0.1.5)
  * jekyll-default-layout (0.1.4)
  * jekyll-feed (0.11.0)
  * jekyll-gist (1.5.0)
  * jekyll-github-metadata (2.12.1)
  * jekyll-mentions (1.4.1)
  * jekyll-optional-front-matter (0.3.0)
  * jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
  * jekyll-readme-index (0.2.0)
  * jekyll-redirect-from (0.14.0)
  * jekyll-relative-links (0.6.0)
  * jekyll-remote-theme (0.3.1)
  * jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
  * jekyll-seo-tag (2.5.0)
  * jekyll-sitemap (1.2.0)
  * jekyll-swiss (0.4.0)
  * jekyll-theme-architect (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-cayman (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-dinky (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-hacker (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-leap-day (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-merlot (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-midnight (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-minimal (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-modernist (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-primer (0.5.3)
  * jekyll-theme-slate (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-tactile (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-theme-time-machine (0.1.1)
  * jekyll-titles-from-headings (0.5.1)
  * jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
  * jemoji (0.10.2)
  * kramdown (1.17.0)
  * liquid (4.0.0)
  * listen (3.1.5)
  * mercenary (0.3.6)
  * mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
  * minima (2.5.0)
  * minitest (5.11.3)
  * multipart-post (2.1.1)
  * nokogiri (1.10.3)
  * octokit (4.14.0)
  * pathutil (0.16.2)
  * public_suffix (3.1.1)
  * rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
  * rb-inotify (0.10.0)
  * rouge (2.2.1)
  * ruby-enum (0.7.2)
  * ruby_dep (1.5.0)
  * rubyzip (1.2.3)
  * safe_yaml (1.0.5)
  * sass (3.7.4)
  * sass-listen (4.0.0)
  * sawyer (0.8.2)
  * terminal-table (1.8.0)
  * thread_safe (0.3.6)
  * typhoeus (1.3.1)
  * tzinfo (1.2.5)
  * unicode-display_width (1.6.0)
```

Expected result is for jekyll is successfully serve the site so I can view it locally on my machine. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why what I did worked but it worked.

I did `gem uninstall -aIx.` and then `bundle install` and everything was back up and running. Source: [getting rid of ruby gems that won't die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000731/getting-rid-of-ruby-gems-that-wont-die).

Comment: Thx man, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Note: the command is `gem uninstall -aIx` with no period `.` (the command failed when the `.` is included) but this still did not resolve the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one, the comparison between the [Gemspec](https://github.com/github/jekyll-commonmark-ghpages/blob/master/jekyll-commonmark-ghpages.gemspec) and your `gem show` does not reveal any issue for me.

Try `gem uninstall jekyll-commonmark-ghpages` and remove all versions of it.

Then install everything again using:

```
  bundle install
  bundle exec jekyll build
```

I have also found this post, related to [rouge on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001686/jekyll-for-github-pages-cant-find-rouge-on-windows), but this is maybe not relevant for you as you are working on Kubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your help Christian, I tried that but that still doesn't work for me.